# Get order of query result according to 'IN' clause in the query  in cake php or mysql

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In cake php is how we can get order of query result according to 'IN' clause in the query

```
$array = array(8,6); // order in 'In' clause
$condition = array('Video.id' => $array);
$videos = $this->Video->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));

//The query will be like below
SELECT * FROM `videos` AS `Video` WHERE `Video`.`id` IN (8,6);
```

Currently it will give result as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Video] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
        )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [Video] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
        )

    )

)
```

I need it like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Video] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
        )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [Video] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
        )

    )

)
```

order Desc or asc will not retreive actual result in order. How it can retreved using cake php ?

I am using cake php, whether this can be done in mysql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER` is an option in CakePHP?

```
$this->Video->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions, 'order' => array('Video.id DESC')));
```

In response to comment:

```
$this->Video->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions, 'order' => array('FIELD(Video.id, 7, 4, 9)')));
```

Comment: what if you search id IN (7,4,9) and want ad order 7-4-9 ?

Comment: so you achieved my solution :)

Comment: Well, it is the solution, so yes. :)

Comment: Thanks for  your answer and it works great.. This way also I get desired result `'order' => array("FIND_IN_SET(Video.id, '8,6')")`

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY FIELD("videos"."id",8,6)
```

i'm quote sure you can use it in cake's find

You can even use the ELT function in this way:

```
ORDER BY ELT(videos.id, 8,1,6,2,n,3,.....)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
$order = array("FIND_IN_SET(Video.id, '8,6')");

$result = $this->Video->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions,'order' => $order);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

The above query can be converted to CakePHP like so:

```
<?php
    $ids = array(1,2,3,4,5);
    $this->Model->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Model.id' => $ids)));
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not write

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` as `Videos` WHERE `Videos`.`id` IN (8,6) ORDER BY `Videos`.`id` DESC
```

It is not a best practice to use `*` in your `SELECT` statement.
Let me know if that helps.

**EDIT**

If needed we can also sort it using another method

```
Order By Case `Video`.`id`
When 8 Then 1
When 1 Then 2
When 3 Then 3 
END
```